# Do you think depressed people relate to dark and depressive internet memes, almost like a coping mechanism?

Tags: depression

For example, [this study found that they could be usefull](https://doi.org/10.1038/s41598-020-57953-4)

Comment: That doesn't seem to be what the study's suggesting, more that dark subjects injected with humour may lift depression. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance as to our ways. What's your question here, could you edit to clarify?

Answer (score 1):

In a similar vein, [research](https://www.thelancet.com/pdfs/journals/lanpsy/PIIS2215-0366(15)00164-9.pdf) shows a link between self-identification with "darkness" and depression, however a causal link in this relationship has not be supported.

More specifically, [Bowes et al. (2015)](https://www.thelancet.com/pdfs/journals/lanpsy/PIIS2215-0366(15)00164-9.pdf) found that teens that identified as "goth" were more likely to self-report depression, as compared to teens who did not identify with this sub-culture. While findings suggest that identification with goth culture is associated with depression, a causal link can not be implied. Data was obtained from the *Avon Longitudinal Study of Parents and Children* (Bowes et al., 2015). Sample participants were approximately 15 years old at the first time point, and 18 years old at the second.

**References**

Bowes, L., Carnegie, R., Pearson, R., Mars, B., Biddle, L., Maughan, B., Lewis, G., Fernyhough, C., & Heron, J. (2015). Risk of depression and self-harm in teenagers identifying with goth subculture: a longitudinal cohort study. The lancet. Psychiatry, 2(9), 793–800. https://doi.org/10.1016/S2215-0366(15)00164-9